# Скриптом не меняется картинка более чем 2 раза

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Делаю блок для выбора типа окна, и при клике должно меняться изображение, срабатывает только 2 раза

```
 function imgsrc(img) {
          if ($(img).attr("src") == "img/oor.png"){
            $(img).attr("src", "img/oh.png");
          }
          if ($(img).attr("src") == "img/oh.png"){
            $(img).attr("src", "img/oor.png");
          }

        }
        $('.imgee').click(function(){
            imgsrc($(this));
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно говоря решение не очень хорошее. У вас условие зависит от src.

```
  $('.imgee').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

  .imgee img:first-child{display:block;}
  .imgee img:last-child{display:none;}
  .imgee.active img:first-child{display:none;}
  .imgee.active img:last-child{display:block;}
```

Comment: Совсем не понял ваш метод, можно детальней?

Comment: Прошу прощения забыл про html. <div class="imgee"><img src="img/oh.png"><img src="img/oor.png"></div>. + css и js который выше

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо правильно обдумать логику `if else`

```js
 function imgsrc(img) {
 console.log($(img).attr("src"));
          if ($(img).attr("src") == "img/oor.png"){
            $(img).attr("src", "img/oh.png");
          } else if ($(img).attr("src") == "img/oh.png"){
            $(img).attr("src", "img/oor.png");
          }

        }
        $('.imgee').click(function(){
            imgsrc($(this));
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="imgee" src="img/oh.png">
```